# Getting body from requests module, Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, request

I am fairly new to Javascript/Node. But I have some programming expierence around Python, Java and C++. However. I can't seem to figure out the scope of the variables. 
For instance, I've got a variable named x and a method, which gets via a get request a body of a sepecific website. Now I want to store it in another variable.

[Dependency I use.](https://github.com/request/request)

My script:

```
const request = require('request');

var x;

request('http://www.google.com', function(err, res, body) {
  return this.x = body;
});

console.log(x); // Should return the "body" from the request method.
```

returns:

```
undefined
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1). The code is slightly different but the concept is the same.

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put just `var x;` at the top scope and assigne the content of x inside of the callback. So what actually happens is

1. Declare variable x
2. Start request to google
3. `Console.log(x);` which is still undefined / null
4. Response from request to Google should arrive, then it will assign the response body to x.

You need to understand that it is async.